# SSIS ADO.DET Performance Issue

Tags: ssis

If I have 20 GB flat file source and want to load it to the SQL server destination using ADO.NET destination and in the process of doing so the performance is very slow.

Please Suggest Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use ADO.net with at least SQL Server 2008 R2, you have to check the dataflox option : `Use bulk insert when possible`

", then you can change dataflow properties like `DefaultBufferMaxRow` and `DefaultBufferSize`and `BatchSize`
Adjusts the value to find the best performances.

On other hand you can try to `drop /recreate indexes/PK` before and after loadding data.

What about `OLE DB destination`? if you are able to use it, it can be a better solution